# Python Port Scanner Stuck In Loop

Tags: python, sockets, port-scanning

I've been following a guide on how to make a simple port scanner, I am trying to scan my own IP but it gets stuck in a loop and prints no ports. It's hard to figure out at it gives no errors and gets stuck in a loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import socket
import subprocess
import sys
from datetime import datetime

#clears the shell screen
subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

#ask for input
remoteServer = raw_input("Please enter a host to scan:")
remoteServerIP = socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)

#print a banner saying we are scanning
print "-" * 60
print "now scanning your host...", remoteServerIP
print "-" * 60

#Check what time the scan started
t1 = datetime.now()

# Using the range function to specify which ports (1 - 1025)

#Errors.

try:
  for port in range(1, 1025):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
    if result == 0:
        #if the socket is listening it will print out the port
      print("Port{}:\t Open".format(port))
    sock.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "You pressed ctrl+c"
  sys.exit()

except socket.gaierror:
  print 'Hostname could not be resolved to IP. Exiting'
  sys.exit()

except socket.error:
  print "couldn't connect to server"
  sys.exit()

# checking the time again
t2 = datetime.now()

#calculates the differnce of time, to see how long it took to run the script
total = t2 - t1

#printing the info to screen
print "scanning compelte in :", total
```

Comment: are you sure you don't get any error message when you run it in console/termina/cmd.exe/powershell ? Maybe put more `print()` to see which port makes problem.

Comment: BTW: as for me cleaning screen is useless - you can't compare current result with previous one.

Comment: what do you mean with "stuck in a loop"?

Comment: I try code and it freeze if I scan non-existing IP or good secured IP like Google DNS - 8.8.8.8

Comment: Works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sock.timeout(0.1)` so it will no wait for connection.

I put `print port` to see which port is scanned.

You can try with `8.8.8.8` - without `sock.timeout(0.1)` it hang on first port.

Maybe you have good secured computer and it blocks connections to close ports.

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import socket

#ask for input
remoteServer = raw_input("Please enter a host to scan: ")
remoteServerIP = socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)

#print a banner saying we are scanning
print "-" * 60
print "now scanning host ...", remoteServerIP
print "-" * 60

#Check what time the scan started
t1 = datetime.now()

# Using the range function to specify which ports (1 - 1025)

#Errors.

try:
  for port in range(1, 1025):
    print port
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    sock.settimeout(0.1)

    result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
    if result == 0:
        #if the socket is listening it will print out the port
        print("Port {:4d}: Open".format(port))
    sock.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "You pressed ctrl+c"
  sys.exit()

except socket.gaierror:
  print 'Hostname could not be resolved to IP. Exiting'
  sys.exit()

except socket.error:
  print "couldn't connect to server"
  sys.exit()

# checking the time again
t2 = datetime.now()

#calculates the differnce of time, to see how long it took to run the script
total = t2 - t1

#printing the info to screen
print "scanning compelte in:", total
```

---

**BTW:**

You can compare your results with results from tools like [nmap](https://nmap.org/)

See [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html) - python module to work with network packages. (book: [Black Hat Python](https://www.nostarch.com/blackhatpython))

---

Answer (score -1):

At least on my machine (Ubuntu 16.something) it does work. Output:

```
Please enter a host to scan:localhost
------------------------------------------------------------
now scanning your host... 127.0.0.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Port21:  Open
Port22:  Open
Port25:  Open
Port80:  Open
Port139:         Open
Port443:         Open
Port445:         Open
Port631:         Open
scanning compelte in : 0:00:00.047478
```

However, it only scans ports 1-1024, while ports go up to 65535.
To make it scan all the ports, change `for port in range(1, 1025):` to `for port in range(1, 65536):`

Comment: it doesn't resolve problem - you could put this as comment.